# Echo and variable expansion

Tags: scripting, variable

I have a script to generate a script:

```bsh
echo '#!/bin/sh'>>rule-1  
echo 'compare() (IFS=" "'>>rule-1  
echo '  exec awk "BEGIN{if (!($*)) exit(1)}"'>>rule-1  
echo ')'>>rule-1  
echo '#Bepaal  percentage memory used.'>>rule-1  
echo "PERC_MEM_USED=$(free | grep Mem | awk '{print $3*100/$2}')">>rule-1  
echo "echo 'Percentage memory used :'">>rule-1  
echo 'echo $PERC_MEM_USED'>>rule-1  
echo 'if compare "$PERC_MEM_USED > 90";'>>rule-1  
echo 'then'>>rule-1  
echo "   echo 'Percentage memory is high.'">>rule-1 
echo '   # PSM data'>>rule-1  
echo "   echo  '(PSM)'">>rule-1  
echo "   echo '(CATEGORY)WARNING(/CATEGORY)'">>rule-1  
echo "   echo '(MESSAGE)Percentage memory is high '$PERC_MEM_USED', please contact ---(MESSAGE)'">>rule-1  
echo "   echo '(/PSM)'">>rule-1  
echo 'fi'>>rule-1
```

When I execute it the generated script is:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh  
compare() (IFS=" "  
  exec awk "BEGIN{if (!($*)) exit(1)}"  
)  
#Bepaal  percentage memory used.  
PERC_MEM_USED=11.9055  
echo 'Percentage memory used :'  
echo $PERC_MEM_USED  
if compare "$PERC_MEM_USED > 90";  
then  
   echo 'Percentage memory is high.'  
   echo '(PSM)'  
   echo '(CATEGORY)WARNING(/CATEGORY)'  
   echo '(MESSAGE)Percentage memory is high '', please contact ---(MESSAGE)'  
   echo '(/PSM)'  
fi
```

The variable `$PERC_MEM_USED` is not expanded in the `(MESSAGE)` line. Any idea, anybody?

Answer (score 2):

The variable is enclosed in double quotes in the generating script, so it gets expanded when running the outer `echo`. Backslash the dollar sign to prevent the expansion. Also, it seems you want the command substitution to run when the generated script is executed, but it currently runs when it's being generated. To fix that, you need to backslash all the dollar signs on the assignment line.

Moreover, instead of appending `>>rule-1` to each line, you can enclose the whole block into curly brackets and add a single `>> rule-1` (or maybe `>`?) after the closing one.

Also, if you switch to a HERE-document, you don't have to repeat the echo and quotes on every line, either.

```
#!/bin/bash
cat <<'EOF' > rule-1
#!/bin/sh
compare() (IFS=" "
  exec awk "BEGIN{if (!($*)) exit(1)}"
)
#Bepaal  percentage memory used.
PERC_MEM_USED=$(free | grep Mem | awk '{print $3*100/$2}')
echo 'Percentage memory used :'
echo $PERC_MEM_USED
if compare "$PERC_MEM_USED > 90";
then
   echo 'Percentage memory is high.'
   # PSM data
   echo  '(PSM)'
   echo '(CATEGORY)WARNING(/CATEGORY)'
   echo '(MESSAGE)Percentage memory is high '$PERC_MEM_USED', please contact ---(MESSAGE)'
   echo '(/PSM)'
fi
EOF
```

Comment: @Kusalananda: Commented and fixed.

Comment: `cat <<-'EOF'` allows for - and strips - a tab indent, which can improve readability in a longer section of code

Answer (score 0):

Thanks choroba,

*The variable is enclosed in double quotes in the generating script, so it gets expanded when running the outer echo. Backslash the dollar sign to prevent the expansion. Also, it seems you want the command substitution to run when the generated script is executed, but it currently runs when it's being generated. To fix that, you need to backslash all the dollar signs on the assignment line.*
....this did the trick :)